# Angular Filter by 2 dates

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to add a Filter of the Date range. Mean I need to show only that data which user input from the date and to date. I have an array of data in which there is only one date is showing. But I want to filter it like this user input any 2 dates (From and To) And in the array I only that data show which are between input dates.

```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
     <div class="content-header">Claims Status</div>
       <p class="content-sub-header">Claims Settled 23</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 <section id="extended">

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
       <div class="card">

    <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-sm bg-primary text-white" style="text-align: center;" ><div>Claims<br>(settled)</div><div *ngIf="statusunsettledcc">  {{statusunsettledcc}}</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-success text-white" style="text-align: center;"><div>Claim Amount<br>(settled)</div><div *ngIf="statusunsettledamount">{{statusunsettledamount | number : fractionSize}}</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-danger text-white" style="text-align: center;" ><div>Claims<br>(unsettled)</div><div *ngIf="status2settledcc">{{status2settledcc}}</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-warning text-white" style="text-align: center;"><div>Claim Amount<br>(unsettled)</div><div *ngIf="status2settledamount">{{status2settledamount | number : fractionSize}}</div></div>
    </div>


  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-title-wrap bar-success">
      <h4 class="card-title">Claims</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-block">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="">Search Name</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.member_name" placeholder="Search name" name="search">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="">Search Claim No</label>
            <input type="search"
            class="form-control" placeholder="Claim No" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.claim_no">
          </div>
        </div>

   <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="from"> //From date
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="to"> //To Date
    </div>


        <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="company">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Company</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.company_id" (change)="getClaims()">
              <option value='' >All</option>
              <option value="999">Airlink Communication</option>
              <option value="637">Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd</option>
              <option value="1053">Frontier Works Organization</option>
              <option value="1174">Ebryx (pvt) Ltd</option>
              <option value="274">HY Enterprises (Pvt) Limited</option>
              <option value="459">Naimat Saleem trust NST (US GROUP)</option>
              <option value="659">Samad Rubber Works (Pvt) Ltd</option>
              <option value="56">Sundry Clients</option>
              <option value="620">TIMEXPERTS (PRIVATE) Limited</option>
              <option value="39">US Apparel & Textile (Pvt) Limited</option>
              <option value="40">US Denim Mills (Pvt) Limited</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Claim Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.status">
              <option value='' >All</option>

              <option value="submitted">Submitted</option>
              <option value="approved">Approved</option>
              <option value="cancel">Objection Claim</option>
              <option value="settled">Settled</option>
              <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
              <option value="CLOSED">Closed</option>
              <option value="OUTSTANDING">Outstanding</option>



            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="policyclaim">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="">Policy</label>
           <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.policy_id" (change)="getClaims()" style="width: 400px" >
             <option value='' >Select Policy No</option>

             <option *ngFor="let policy of policynumbers" value="{{policy.policy_id}}">{{policy.policy_id}}</option>

           </select>
         </div>
       </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="policysamad">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="">Policy</label>
           <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.policy_id" (change)="getSamad()" style="width: 400px" >
             <option value='' >Select Policy No</option>

             <option *ngFor="let policy of policynumbers" value="{{policy.policy_id}}">{{policy.policy_id}}</option>

           </select>
         </div>
       </div>


     </div>



     <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>STATUS</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Patient Name</th>
          <th>Approved Amount</th>
          <th>Claimed Amount</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Submitted By</th>
          <th>Claim No</th>
          <!-- <th>Website URL</th> -->

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="data1">



        <tr *ngFor="let x of data1 | filterBy: userFilter" (click)="openDeal(deletecontent, x)" >





          <td>
            <span class="text-success" *ngIf="x.status == 'submitted'">Submitted</span>
            <span class="text-primary" *ngIf="x.status == 'settled'">Settled</span>
            <span class="text-warning" *ngIf="x.status == 'rejected'">Rejected</span>
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="x.status == 'Approved'">Approved</span>
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="x.status == 'ojection claim'">Objection claim</span>


          </td>
          <td >
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image-png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="" style="text-align: left;">
              {{x.member_name}}
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: left;">{{x.patient_name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.approved_value}}</td>
          <td>{{x.claimed_value}}</td>
          <td>                                      



            <span  class="text-success" *ngIf="x.company_id == '999'" >Airlink Communication</span>
            <span class="text-success" *ngIf="x.company_id == '637'">Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '1053'" class="text-success">Frontier Works Organization</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '1174'" class="text-success">Ebryx (pvt) Ltd</span>
            <span  *ngIf="x.company_id == '274'" class="text-success">HY Enterprises (Pvt) Limited</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '459'" class="text-success">Naimat Saleem trust NST (US GROUP)</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '659'" class="text-success">Samad Rubber Works (Pvt) Ltd</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '56'" class="text-success">Sundry Clients</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '620'" class="text-success">TIMEXPERTS (PRIVATE) Limited</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '39'" class="text-success">US Apparel & Textile (Pvt) Limited</span>
            <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '40'" class="text-success">US Denim Mills (Pvt) Limited</span>


          </td>

          <td>{{x.submitted_at || 'not-defined'}}

          </td>
          <td>{{x.claim_no}}</td>

        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

.ts

```
getClaims(){

this.policyclaim = true;


if(this.userFilter.company_id){
this.url = 'url='+this.userFilter.company_id;

this.httpClient.get<any>('url'+this.userFilter.company_id).subscribe(statuses => {
  console.log(statuses);
  console.log(statuses.records[0].Amount);
  this.statusunsettledamount = statuses.records[0].Amount;
  console.log(this.statusunsettledamount);
    console.log(statuses.records[0].cc);
    this.statusunsettledcc = statuses.records[0].cc;

});

this.httpClient.get<any>('url'+this.userFilter.company_id).subscribe(statuses2 => {
  console.log(statuses2);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].Amount);
    this.status2settledamount = statuses2.records[0].Amount;
    console.log(this.status2settledamount);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].cc);
    this.status2settledcc = statuses2.records[0].cc;
    console.log(this.status2settledcc);
});

this.httpClient.get<any>('url'+this.userFilter.company_id).subscribe(policyinfo => {
  console.log(policyinfo);
  this.policynumbers = policyinfo.records;
  console.log(this.policynumbers);
});


}

  if (this.from && this.to) {
    const fromDate = new Date(this.from.split(/\D/));
    const toDate = new Date(this.to.split(/\D/));
    this.data1.filter(obj => new Date(obj.date) > fromDate && new Date(obj.date) < toDate);
    console.log(this.data1);
  }


else 
{
this.url = 'url/get_claims.php?offset=0&limit=50';

this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_claims_amt.php?cstatus=OUTSTANDING').subscribe(statuses => {
  console.log(statuses);
  console.log(statuses.records[0].Amount);
  this.statusunsettledamount = statuses.records[0].Amount;
  console.log(this.statusunsettledamount);
    console.log(statuses.records[0].cc);
    this.statusunsettledcc = statuses.records[0].cc;

});

this.httpClient.get<any>('url/get_claims_amt.php?cstatus=CLOSED').subscribe(statuses2 => {
  console.log(statuses2);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].Amount);
    this.status2settledamount = statuses2.records[0].Amount;
    console.log(this.status2settledamount);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].cc);
    this.status2settledcc = statuses2.records[0].cc;
    console.log(this.status2settledcc);
});


this.httpClient.get<any>('url/insurance-api/get_company_policy.php?').subscribe(policyinfo => {
  console.log(policyinfo);
  this.policynumbers = policyinfo.records;
  console.log(this.policynumbers);
});


}

this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).
subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
this.spinner.hide();

this.data1 = data.records;
this.data1.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
console.log(this.userFilter.policy_id);




if(this.userFilter.policy_id){

let vv = this.data1.filter(v => v.policy_id === this.userFilter.policy_id);
console.log(vv);

this.httpClient.get<any>('http://url='+this.userFilter.policy_id).subscribe(statuses => {
  console.log(statuses);
  console.log(statuses.records[0].Amount);
  this.statusunsettledamount = statuses.records[0].Amount;
  console.log(this.statusunsettledamount);
    console.log(statuses.records[0].cc);
    this.statusunsettledcc = statuses.records[0].cc;

});

this.httpClient.get<any>('url='+this.userFilter.policy_id).subscribe(statuses2 => {
  console.log(statuses2);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].Amount);
    this.status2settledamount = statuses2.records[0].Amount;
    console.log(this.status2settledamount);
    console.log(statuses2.records[0].cc);
    this.status2settledcc = statuses2.records[0].cc;
    console.log(this.status2settledcc);
});



this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_company_policy.php?company_id='+this.company_id).subscribe(policyinfo => {
  console.log(policyinfo);
  this.policynumbers = policyinfo.records;
  console.log(this.policynumbers);
});

this.url = 'url/get_claims.php?';

this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,
{
params: {
policy_id: this.userFilter.policy_id     
 },

}).
subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
this.spinner.hide();

this.data1 = data.records;
this.data1.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
console.log(this.userFilter.policy_id);

});





//const sum1 = vv.filter(item => item.status === 'settled')
//.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
//console.log(sum1);
//this.sum1 = sum1;

//const sum2 = vv.filter(item => item.status === 'submitted')
//.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
//console.log(sum2);
//this.sum2 = sum2;

//var status = 'settled';
//var status2 = 'submitted';

//var countsettled = vv.filter((obj) => obj.status === status).length;
//var countunsettled = vv.filter((obj) => obj.status === status2).length;

//console.log(countsettled);
//this.countsettled = countsettled;
//console.log(countunsettled);
//this.countunsettled = countunsettled;



}
//else{


//const sum1 = this.data1.filter(item => item.status === 'settled')
//.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
//console.log(sum1);
//this.sum1 = sum1;

//const sum2 = this.data1.filter(item => item.status === 'submitted')
//.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
//console.log(sum2);
//this.sum2 = sum2;

//var status = 'settled';
//var status2 = 'submitted';

//var countsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => obj.status === status).length;
//var countunsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => obj.status === status2).length;

//console.log(countsettled);
//this.countsettled = countsettled;
//console.log(countunsettled);
//this.countunsettled = countunsettled;



//}


});



}
```

Comment: Are the date filters independent of `userFilter`?

Comment: no im using userfilter just for name etc. and filter date seperately.

Comment: Where is the date property of the data? If you have it you could use `*ngIf` with a function returning a boolean based on whether the data's date is between `from` and `to`. Then wrap that `*ngIf` around the data you want to filter

Comment: I see.. Ok. Just wondering, is the date property contain a Date object? Or is it a string? What is the format?

Comment: it is a string .

Comment: @Jojofoulk can you please give any sample code ? thanks

Comment: The function you call in your `*ngIf` would process the date's data and parse it as a Date object inside your .ts file,(something like `*ngIf="isValidDate(data.date)"`) The function then compares data.date to `from` and `to` which are component variable already.

Comment: sorry but not understanding this . Can you please give a code how can i use in my code ? Thanks

Comment: @UmaizKhan Can you please give me a sample of how your date string looks like? `2019-05-01` Is it like, `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Comment: DD-MM-YY This is the format

Comment: So it is something like 11-05-2019? Or 11-05-19?

Comment: 11-JUL-18  DD-MMM-YY

Answer (score 0):

filter you array based on the user dates. prefer any date picker on the input for to and from to pick date objects and avoiding extra overhead. I prefer moment for date comparison and filtering. for faster data filtering also refer **cross filter**. It is way too fast than normal filtering despite of any length of array.

Comment: Can you please provide code ? i dont know how ill filter it . Thanks

Comment: `cf = crossfilter(data)
date_dimension = cf.dimension((d) => d.date)
values = date_dimension.filter([to, from]).top(Infinity)`

You can use these filtered records then. make sure to, from and date are in same format.

Comment: refer the doc for more info. [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference). Also you can use [bootstrap_datepicker_angular](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) for date selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch on how you can solve that problem. It probably won't work if you copy and paste directly, but this should nudge you in the right direction.

You can filter the data by using the `ngModelChange` event binding on both date inputs.

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onDateSelection($event)" [(ngModel)]="from"> //From date
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onDateSelection($event)" [(ngModel)]="to"> //To Date
</div>
```

And on your Component.ts, you might want to create a shallow copy of your data so that we can use that copy for filtering purposes. Then, we define the `onDateSelection()` method. We decode the date inputs, and convert them into the javascript Date object. Then, we filter them accordingly.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.temp = [...this.data1];
}

onDateSelection() {
  if (this.from && this.to) {
    const fromDate = new Date(this.from.split(/\D/));
    const toDate = new Date(this.to.split(/\D/));
    this.data1 = this.temp.filter(obj => new Date(obj.date) > fromDate && new Date(obj.date) < toDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i add the function in question where im fetching data. Can you please check and tell me how can i use this in that code ? Thanks again

Comment: The above method should work without the involvement of your fetching of data. This is because the filtering is done after the data and the table is rendered.

Comment: its showing date like this 2019-01-01 can i take input like 01-JUL-01 DD-MMM-YY

Comment: Yes, you can rearrange the input to the required format, as long as it can be parsed into a date object. My logic is to convert them to date objects so that we can carry out the date comparison when we filter it

Comment: in input we can take input in DD-MMM-YY this formal ? i think if we take in this format then it will show result because in data  the date format is also this

Answer (score 0):

First transform your "data1" adding a propertie "date" that was a string of the date of the form YYYYmmdd. You can use this function to add a propertie: companyName and statusName to avoid yours *ngIf. I don't prove but can be like

```
companies=[{id:999,name:"Airlink Communication"},{id:637,name:"Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd"},..]

const months=[{month:"00",name:"ENE"},{month:"01",name:"FEB"}...]
dataFormated=data.map(x=>{
   const company=companies.find(c=>c.id==x.company_id);
   const status=x.status.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+x.status.substr(1)
   const datepart=x.submitted_at.split('-');
   const date=''+datepart[2]+month.find(m=>m.name==datepart[1]).month+datepart[0]
   //date becomes, e.g. "180611" for x.submited_at "11-JUL-18"

   return 
     {
         ...x,
         companyName:company?company.name:'',
         status:status
         date:date
     }
})
```

Well, then you can filter using the new propertie "date" -is a string, you can use a filter or an if-

**Updated** the filter becomes like

```
if (this.from && this.to) {
    //first convert this.from and this.to to string of form YYmmdd
    //your'e using simply html input type date that return a string
    //I suggested you use mat-datepicker or ng-datepicker, but in your case
    const fromDate = new Date(this.from.split(/\D/));
    const toDate = new Date(this.to.split(/\D/));

    //see how convert a number in string with 2 digits using slice(-2), 
    //e.g. ('0'+2).slice(-2) is "02"
    const fromDateTxt=''+(fromDate.getFullYear()%100)+
      ('0'+fromDate.getMonth()+1).slice(-2)+
      ('0'+fromDate.getDate()).slice(-2)

    const toDateTxt=''+(toDate.getFullYear()%100)+
      ('0'+toDate.getMonth()+1).slice(-2)+
      ('0'+toDate.getDate()).slice(-2)

    this.data1=dataFormated.filter(
          obj => obj.date >= fromDateTxt && obj.date< toDateTxt);
    console.log(this.data1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i add the function in question where im fetching data. Can you please check and tell me how can i use this in that code ? Thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer. The reason to using string -nor date object- is the efficency. You only has to transform the "from" and "to". But really, I don't undestand so much your code. In general, in Angular we use a service to return the observables -the httpClient.get-, and susbcribe in the component. You need decided if you want to transform the data adding the properties companyName and date in the service -using http.get(...).pipe(map(......)- or after subscribe

Comment: its showing empty array but there is date in selected dates . and i need to transform after subscribe .

Comment: its showing result now but not showing result correct.